# Readonly file and editable form in document library of SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, flow, power-automate

Is there a way to set the form of a document library editable but having the document as read only (After create the item, of course) in SharePoint Online?

If it is useful, I can use Power Automate.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it seems to be impossible. You need at least edit permission level to edit the form and there is no action to set permission level in Power Automate.

Comment: There isn't an action to change permission level, but it is throught SharePoint API, which can be requested by Power Automate, so... how can I do that with permission levels?